# How to properly mock i18next

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-i18next

Here is a simplified version of both my function and test. Although I mocked the useTranslation I get the following error:

> You are passing an undefined module! Please check the object you are
> passing to i18next.use()

> ```
>    7 | i18n
>    8 |   .use(Backend)
> >  9 |   .use(initReactI18next)
> ```

How do I properly mock to get rid of this error?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import * as Constants from 'constants'
import MyComponent from 'components'

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('dashboard')
  return (
     <div> Dashboard 
      <MyComponent name={t(Constants.MYCOMPONENT)}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key) => key })
}))
it('Render Dashboard without crash', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard/>, div)

})
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted, I'm stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I could get this to work for our setup was the following:

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    initReactI18next: { type: "3rdParty", init: jest.fn() },
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key }),
    Trans: ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => children,
}));
```

With `initReactI18next: { type: "3rdParty", init: jest.fn() },`

Being the final piece of the puzzle, as referenced [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1426#issuecomment-828656983)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mock `i18next`, this lib supports [`cimode`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) which will always return the passed key.

In order to enable it, all you need to do is to pass `cimode` as `lang` in the config.

In your tests env setup change the language to `cimode`:

```js
await i18next.changeLanguage('cimode');

// from now all calls to `t('MY_TARANSLATION_KEY')` 
// will return the key (in this case `MY_TARANSLATION_KEY`)
```

Comment: Please can you expand on this, with code samples if possible. I don't understand where this should be set in relation to the tests. I followed the link for the `cimode` but it still wasn't clear to me.